# List of references and EANs

Tags: mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How to get a list of EANs and references from all products in prestashop?

I am using a prestashop 1.5 and mysql database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ean13, reference FROM `ps_product_attribute
```